# Referenciar uma pergunta duplicada quando há centenas de duplicatas

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

Exemplo: [Como enviar formulário sem dar refresh na página?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94019/como-enviar-formulario-sem-dar-refresh-na-pagina)

Enviar "form" sem refresh é um pedido muito recorrente.

Vi essa nova pergunta hoje e pensei em linkar com uma já existente. Porém, a pesquisa retorna centenas de perguntas idênticas.

Claro que cada uma tem uma peculiaridade, porém, o conceito e técnicas são os mesmos.

Do meu ponto de vista, são todas duplicadas.

Fiquei em dúvida sobre qual resposta escolher para linkar pois há centenas e eu não vou olhar 1 a 1. Custa muito tempo, tornando-se inviável.

Existe algum meio de resolver ou uma política do StackOverflow em relação a isso?

Uma ideia que me surgiu é criar um artigo, uma pergunta com resposta wiki. Então poderíamos linkar todas essas duplicadas para essa resposta wiki. E talvez adotar isso como padrão para outros casos.

Comment: Acredito que ja deva ter uma resposta canônica sobre esse assunto, o maior problema mesmo é fazer o OP abstrair os detalhes dessa pergunta para o problema dele, com certeza ele vai alegar que são pergunta diferentes por causa de X ou Y.

Comment: O que eu faço quando estou pesquisando um certo assunto que tem muitas perguntas iguais é http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=FORMUL%C3%81RIO%20ajax por exemplo, e à partir daí encontro as perguntas e respostas mais votadas para aquele assunto. Neste caso, acho que [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91147/quando-usar-e-n%C3%A3o-usar-ajax-no-envio-de-formul%C3%A1rios/91155#91155) e [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17630/como-enviar-e-processar-n-formul%C3%A1rios-distintos-com-ajax-sem-dar-refresh-na-pagi/17634#17634) são as melhores.

Comment: Se você fala de "centenas" de duplicatas e não mostra um exemplo.... Quais as *search queries* que usou para fazer a pesquisa básica? Tentou organizar por tags e por votos?

Comment: pesquisei algo como "página refresh" ou "enviar refresh".. pesquise vc mesmo e verá que mesmo com diferentes keywords retorna muita coisa.. "centenas" não é um número exato.. podem retornar "dezenas", o que também é muito de qualquer forma e eu não fico aqui 24 horas todos os dias para dar tal dedicação para algo tão pequeno.. se eu não encontro algo rápido já caio fora, entende? Não vou ficar tentando filtro disso e daquilo e fuçando combinações.. Isso custa muito tempo. Tenho outras coisas para fazer na vida como dar tempo a familia, filhos, coisas pessoais e trabalho.

Comment: não entendi o negativo na questão.. nem ao menos é uma crítica, não fala nada de mais .. é meramente uma consulta ...  povo doido que sai dando negativo a esmo..

Comment: Votei -1 muito racionalmente pelos motivos expostos no meu comentário anterior e posso reavaliar o voto se a pergunta for editada. Ou seja, não foi "doido" nem a "esmo".